# Geocoding in android Api Charges?

Tags: android, location, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

Hi does geocoding and reverse geocoding  android api charges?

If yes then how much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Geocoding is the process of transforming a street address or other
>   description of a location into a (latitude, longitude) coordinate
>
> Reverse geocoding is the process of transforming a (latitude,
>   longitude) coordinate into a (partial) address.

It is the Inbuilt android Class . It is Free . Android API are free to use.

[Click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#pubctors) for more information .

Comment: From those docs: "The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in the core android framework. The Geocoder query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform." So what does this mean?